# Prevent feature branch to merge to master

Tags: git, githooks, git-flow

Is there a hook-type that helps me to prevent the merge/PR of certain branch types to master? I only want to allow hotfix/ and release/ branches to be merged to master.

I'm currently using Gitflow, and my team have adapted smoothly, the thing is, one of the developers threw a PR from his feature branch to master instead of develop, all the reviewers omitted this and merged the branch, no one noticed the merge was to master and, when a hotfix branch was created from master, the code from that feature/ branch went to production and caused many troubles.

We made a regression before going to production, but the new code was database dependant and specific to certain process so we didn't caught it.

I know this was an error in the process, but still I want to protect the master branch from this kind of human-error.

Comment: How should Git know which branches are allowed to be merged?

Comment: How are you performing the merges?  With some Git server implementation or manually?

Comment: @mkrieger1 With branch prefixes.

Comment: @bk2204 We manage our repository through Bitbucket